react native sdk issue :com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0
My React native("react-native": "0.72.3") project is running as expected in production and test environments. As per the new Google developer policy, I have increased the API version after that, now when I want release a new version of .aab file in playconsole it shows this error
Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0 Maven dependency to an Android 14 
compatible version! Your current com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0 library is 
incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards- 
incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder, from 31 August 2024, Google 
Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest library 
version dependency to avoid app crashes.

